# iOS12.1.2 Keyboard issues in the app created in Phonegap

Tags: cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, iphone-x, ios12

I am having a weird issue for a mobile app created in PhoneGap which is working fine for android version 9.0 (pie) but not for iOS 12.1.2

I am using the following configuration in config.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
  <name>eWatch Online</name>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
  <preference name="deployment-target" value="6.0" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="15000" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="WebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />

  <plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" spec="1.1.1" source="pgb" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <access origin="*" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" onload="true" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" onload="true" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.devexpress.plugins.devextremeaddon" version="1.0.1" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.13" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.2.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5" />
  <gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" version="1.2.0" />
</widget>
```

attaching the screenshot of error

[image]

I have tried with latest Phonegap-version cli-8.1.1. also I have tried changing gap:plugins to the latest but unable to get success.
Please help as I am new in hybrid application development. Thanks in advance.